# Access VBA ImportXML method only imports last record from XML file

Tags: xml, ms-access, asp.net-web-api, vba

I'm trying to import a very basic XML file into MS Access (2010) using the Application.ImportXML method. When I view the results of the import, the table only contains the last record from the XML file.

For starters - I have created a small ASP.NET Web Application (VB.NET) in Visual Studio 2017 which has a single Controller `PersonController.vb`. I've left the default methods alone & I have the current values set up -

```vb
Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Return New String() {"Person1", "Person2"}
End Function
```

When I run this through `IIS Express (Google Chrome)` I can view the XML results through Postmaster as seen below -

```vb
["Person1","Person2"]
```

Or if I select json -

```vb
[
    "Person1",
    "Person2"
]
```

I'm opting for XML.

So now to my Access VBA. I've created a fresh module to test the importing of XML into a local Access Table -

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const URL As String = "http://localhost:58372/api/Person"
Private Const path As String = "C:/Users/my.name/Desktop/"

Public Enum RequestReadyState
    UNINITIALISED = 0
    LOADING
    LOADED
    INTERACTIVE
    COMPLETED
End Enum
```

When I manually go to `http://localhost:58372/api/Person/` I get the desired output. I'm having a bit of an issue with the VBA side of things.

**Note - I've added a reference to the `Microsoft XML, v6.0` library for this**

```vb
Public Sub Readxml()
    Dim reader As New XMLHTTP60, doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    With reader
    ' open the object
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
    ' send the command specified in the open
        .send

    ' wait until the request is complete, 4 is the completed state
    ' see (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms753800(v=vs.85))
        Do Until .ReadyState = RequestReadyState.COMPLETED
            DoEvents
        Loop

        ' check if we encountered an error
        ' status codes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)
        If .Status = 200 Then
            ' it worked
            Set doc = .responseXML
            doc.Save path & "Person.xml"
            Application.ImportXML path & "Person.xml", acStructureAndData
        Else
            ' it didn't
            MsgBox "It broke: " & .Status & " : " & .statusText
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

' clean up
    Set reader = Nothing
    If Not doc Is Nothing Then Set doc = Nothing
    Kill path & "Person.xml"
End Sub
```

The sub runs to completion without any error, however when I open the newly created table `ArrayOfstring` it only contains 1 record which is "Person2".

I've tried working this out but I'm lost. `doc.childNodes.length` returns 1 (should be 2 records?) but I don't understand why.

I've used [this XML Validation site](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/) to try & help me understand if it's a problem with the XML that's being generated, when I tick the option to validate against the external XML schema it gives me the following error -

`cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ArrayOfstring'.`

XML file contents -

```vb
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <string>Person1</string>
  <string>Person2</string>
</ArrayOfstring>`
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction / spot something obvious I've missed here? Sorry if I've rambled a bit, just a bit confused about this whole thing.

**Edit**: I've updated the reference to use Microsoft XML, v3.0 & updated the object types to reflect the new reference but I'm still getting the same issue.

**Edit2: Update**: The below answer stating to convert to a different type of XML does work, however I've chosen to roll with a different solution. To avoid having to use local tables, I've set the header request to use JSON & then I'm parsing it into a collection to use within the application. I've found this approach to be smoother for my setup.

Comment: FWIW I tried and see the same thing. Also tried first creating the table then appending the data - same behavior. Can't find any other mentions of this anywhere in a Google search... Access 2010.

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister, I've been struggling to find any similar behaviour online myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

Current results make sense since Access' XML migration renders node names as columns and text values as row values, ignoring any attributes. Specifically, below format

```
<table_name>
  <col1>value1</col1>
  <col2>value2</col2>
</table_name>
```

becomes:

```
table_name

  col1    col2
value1  value2
```

However, because your XML response contains two same named nodes (allowable in XML) and database tables cannot have same named columns, only the last instance of *string* is retained as column.

**Solution**

To resolve, after you download your XML via `GET` request, consider running XSLT, the special-purpose language to transform XML files, to convert nodes to *string1* and *string2*:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                              xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/doc:ArrayOfstring">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:string"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc:string">
    <xsl:element name="{concat(local-name(), position())}" 
                 namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**VBA**

```vb
Public Sub XMLResposeTransform()

On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    ' ADD MSXML, v6.0 REFERENCE UNDER TOOLS
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load "Input.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.Load "XSLT_Script.xsl"

    ' TRANSFORM XML
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "Output.xml"

    Application.ImportXML "Output.xml", acStructureAndData

    MsgBox "Successfully imported the transformed XML!", vbInformation

ExitHandle:
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbInformation
    Resume ExitHandle

End Sub
```

XML Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <string1>Person1</string1>
    <string2>Person2</string2>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

Access table

```
ArrayOfstring

string1    string2
Person1    Person2
```

---

If your XML file had multiple elements of repeating children, then multiple rows would propagate:

Hypothetical XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <newtable>
    <string1>Person1</string1>
    <string2>Person2</string2>
  </newtable>
  <newtable>
    <string1>Person1</string1>
    <string2>Person2</string2>
  </newtable>
  <newtable>
    <string1>Person1</string1>
    <string2>Person2</string2>
  </newtable>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

Access table

```
newtable

string1    string2
Person1    Person2
Person1    Person2
Person1    Person2
```

Comment: Are you saying that it's not possible to import multiple *rows* for a given column?

Comment: No. Just that you cannot create a table of two same named columns. If there is a parent above the *strings* that repeats, then that becomes the name of the table and the repeating *strings* becomes rows. See edit to show. Once again, child nodes cannot repeat.

Comment: @Parfait I'm not sure if I'll be able to use this to work based on my scenario, if I can I'm sorry but could you clarify a bit further? The original XML is being created from my GET request. I'm using the application/xml header value to get the information out. When I've tried using xsl/xslt I haven't received a valid file to work with.

Comment: Continue to use your `GET` request. But then as an added step, run this solution. I see you save the XML: `doc.Save path & "Person.xml"`. Then, use this as the *Input.xml* in this solution. Be sure to create the proposed XSLT script (.xsl file).

Comment: @Parfait Thanks a lot for your help, sorry for the delay in getting back to you (I'm not being ungrateful) just had a hectic week. I'm struggling a bit with the XSLT script. Are you saying I need to manually create this prior to running your solution, or am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Yes, create XSLT as instructed: *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*. Then reference the file in VBA: `xslDoc.Load "XSLT_Script.xsl"`.